# How do I view an HTML email, in plain text, using Yahoo Mail?

Tags: yahoo-mail

For development purposes, I need to view an HTML email as plain text, using Yahoo Mail. How do I do that?

Comment: I am confused - do you want to see your Yahoo mail or do you want to see the HTML email using the Yahoo Mail application ?

Comment: I have an HTML email in my yahoo inbox. I want to see the raw email (i.e. the email 'source').

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) then Right Click anywhere in the message body and click on "Inspect Element". Now find the IFrame with class "messageArea". Right click on all content between `<iframe>` and `</iframe>` and and click on "Copy as HTML" button. Paste it on any text editor (like Notepad). This is the source of the message body.

Answer (score 1):

One trick to view an html message in plain text in Yahoo mail:

- view the message, then click on forward
- click on the << ("switch to plain text") control.
  The message is immediately converted to plain text.  You can
  then forward it to yourself or read it as is or cut and paste.

The << control is on the same line as the "Send" button, font change and spell check controls.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from chanchal1987's answer - if it's just the headers you want to view, click ACTIONS > VIEW FULL HEADER for a small popup with the email headers.